# Mouse Pointer is blinking and some time disappear

Tags: 14.04, mouse

After upgrade to Ubuntu 14.04 my mouse pointer is blinking and some time it's disappear, I don't know why this happening

I search lots of for this issue and I get some results but unable to get solutions.

This is my display in Settings -> Display

[image]

Comment: For my laptop, the solution was ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Disable the "Unknown Display" in Display settings.

Comment: How to disable, please see the screenshot and give me steps

Comment: Klick on the "Unknown Display" und move the according "On/Off" Slider to "Off".

Comment: there are two on/off button (see in screenshot above) 1. Built-in-Display and 2. Sticky Edges. When select Unknown Display from Launcher Placement - then nothing happen, I do all off but still not working.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot of where you selected and disabled the Unknown Display?

Answer (score 2):

In your first screen shot, where you have a pink/red rectangle and a green one, this screen indicates two monitors, being one for each color. It's like your ubuntu is seeing two monitors. This second one, indicated by the green square, is what some people told you here as being the Unknown Display.

You should click this green square in order to see the configurations for this display.
When you do so, your "Built-in display" button will be now named "Unknown Display" and you should set this to off.

Setting it to off will turn the green screen to gray.

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem together with two duplicate screens showing inside a particular workspace while switching them. After I disabled the `unknown display` this problem was resolved too. I do not know why that option is on my default anyways.